# ObjectFactory with Class<?> argument

Tags: java, class, generics, objectfactory

I'm developing a factory which can instantiate objects of type Ability by using Class parameter. The code for this factory is:

```
public static final class AbilityFactory {
    private AbilityFactory(){}

    public static <T extends Class<A>, A extends Ability> A getAbility(T clazz){
        A ability = null;
        try{
            ability = clazz.newInstance();
        } catch(InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ability;
    }
}
```

Client code is something like that:

```
Ability.AbilityFactory.getAbility(Firebolt.class));
```

The only problem I figured about this design is that Ability class is **abstract** and you can pass something like this:

```
Ability.AbilityFactory.getAbility(Ability.class));
```

which results in **java.lang.InstantiationException**.

I wanted to know whether I can make some constraints like "? extends Ability but not Ability" or it's just a bad design and I should pass, for example, Enum as an argument into factory's method to prevent this situation.

Comment: I don't see why that would be a problem, just don't pass Ability.class as parameter.

Comment: If all your `Ability` subclasses have a default constructor, and you need to have the `Class` object to instantiate it using this factory, then what is the point? Why not just use the new operator, and avoid reflection?

Comment: @FINDarkside well then the whole purpose of generics is fading away. You can't determine a wrong argument at compile time.

Comment: @bali182 because instead of **Champion<Azae> azae = new Azae(new Firebolt(), new Rend());** I want **Champion<Azae> azae = new Azae(Firebolt.class, Rend.class);**

Comment: Then maybe you might want to look at some dependency injection frameworks, like [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice) or [Dagger](https://github.com/square/dagger). They do this a much more robust and mature way, than what you or me can put together in a few hours ;)

Comment: @bali182 Thanks, but I do this in purpose of studying)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you could do is to provide a marker interface let's say `ConcreteAbility` and have `<T extends Ability & ConcreteAbility>`. Then you need to implement ConcreteAbility with all concrete abilities.

Comment: It seems to be a good advice, but now I can't pass well bounded argument into my Champion's constructor. Before it was  **public Champion(Class<? extends Ability<C>> firstAbility){...}** and after I modified my factory following your advice : **public static <T extends Class<A>, A extends Ability & ConcreteAbility> A getAbility(T clazz){...}** I need in my constructor something like **Class<? extends Ability<C> & ConcreteAbility>**, but that is not an option because of wrong syntax. Can you advice me some workaround?

Comment: Well, it really helped me. I forgot we can use named type parameters in the constructors too. Thanks!) The code for my constructor is now: **public <T extends Class<A>, A extends Ability & ConcreteAbility> Champion(T firstAbility, T secondAbility){...}**

Comment: Btw. you don't need T, unless you really have your own Class implementation — which, seeing that `java.lang.Class` is final, is highly unlikely. Thus your constructor can be simplified to `public <A extends Ability & ConcreteAbility> Champion(Class<A> firstAbility…)`